# Continuous random variables with zero variance

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a very simple question. I heard in my class that a random variable is equal to zero if its variance is equal to zero. I understand that if the variance of a random variable is zero, then that random variable must be a constant. But if it is a continuous random variable, does that mean that the random variable is equal to zero (since it cannot take a particular value)?

Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. If the variance is zero then the function has the same value ae. What do you mean by a continuous rv? Do you mean the function or its distribution?

Comment: $X$ doesn't have to be zero if it has zero variance. If however $X$ has zero mean, then that would imply $X$ is degenerate at zero. (And if $X$ takes a constant value, how can it be continuous?)

Comment: You heard wrong.  A random variable is constant (not necessarily $0$) if its variance is $0$.  If it is constant, it is not a continuous random variable.